# What exactly are the benefits of keeping a Hamiltonian system of equations Hamiltonian during solving or transformation?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics

When faced with a system of differential equations that happens to be Hamiltonian in form, or a perturbation of a Hamiltonian system, we often see in classical work a clear attempt to pursue solutions or analyses that maintain the Hamiltonian nature of the problem (e.g. Liouville flow in phase space), typically by limiting oneself to canonical or symplectic transformations. I read (e.g. see [Jose and Saletan's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521636361), p.336) that sticking to the Hamiltonian dynamical nature would benefit the treatment because Hamiltonian dynamics and perturbation theory are "better understood" in general. But the meaning of this assertion it is still not very clear to me.

If one is interested in solving such a system of equations (e.g. finding the equations of motion) and looks at it from the point of view of a differential set of equations, why not just attack it using the various differential equation techniques (e.g. methods like those in [Bender and Orzag's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387989315) classic), regardless of being Hamiltonian or not? Is there a clear theory/practice that predicts insolubility in general if solubility couldn't be found while staying Hamiltonian?  What are exactly the benefits of keeping things Hamiltonian, and could one, perhaps, solve such a problem outside the Hamiltonian description when it couldn't be solved in canonical methods?

Comment: Look up symplectic integrators